# From PostgreSQL to Cassandra - Aggregation functions not supported

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, cassandra, datastax, nosql-aggregation

I need your advise please. I have an application that runs on PostgreSQL but takes too long to bring back data.
I would like to use Cassandra but noticed that CQL does not support aggregation.
Would that be possible with Hadoop or am I going completely the wrong way?
Also all the dates are stored in Epoch, and CQL can't convert them.

What would be the best approach to convert an application that runs on PostGreSQL to Cassandra?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Cassandra introduced aggregate functions in 2.2 with [CASSANDRA-4914](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4914).  The documentation for using the standard (built in) functions is [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useQueryStdAggregate.html) and for creating custom aggregate functions is [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDA.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer Mike. That was very helpful. I assume I will have to normalize the dates from Epoch before I add them to the table.